# android - save file to internal storage

Tags: android, io, storage

I know this is a double post but the other threads didn't answer my question.
I want to write a file to the directory of my app inside the Android directory in the internal storage

I added the permission to the manifest:

**Manifest.xml** Code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and **Java** code:

```
 File myPath = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.dat");            
    myPath.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        fos.write(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

however the directory for my app is not created and I cannot find the filename via search.

**EDIT:**
there is actually a FileNotFoundException thrown, my bad.
But I thought that mkdirs() would create all missing directories.

Comment: Use runtime permisssion  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Internal storage doesn't require runtime permissions

Comment: Can you do e.printStackTrace(); in your exception to see what is the issue

Comment: please provide code of getFilesDir()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with below:

```
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file =  new File(directory,”fileName”);
String data = “TEST DATA”;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(“fileName”, true); // save
fos.write(data.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This will write the file in to the Device's internal storage at `/data/user/0/com.yourapp/`

Comment: do we need to give  file permission for this ?

Comment: and how to read?

Answer (score 4):

try this way

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/filename";

            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

           // File file = new File(dir, "filename");
```

Comment: This might work but is a different approach. To store in internal storage it is not necessary to have a folder structure after absolute path. This doesn't tell him where he made a mistake.

Comment: you can directly write file name instead of that it will work ,try it see my edited answer file will be creaet at your internal storage

Comment: I tried it, has the same outcome -> FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 3):

> however the directory for my app is not created and I cannot find the filename via search.

You, as a user, have no access to your app's portion of what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which is what you are using.

Users have access to what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make comments, due to too low reputation, so I need to answer this way. I would slightly modify #AndroidDevUser answer, changing:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(“fileName”, true);
```

with

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Additionally I would add try / catch block.

```
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file =  new File(directory,"fileName");
    String data = "TEST DATA";
    FileOutputStream fos = null; // save
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```